# Rust diesel Postgres how to add pagination to query

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using the [diesel](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/) to connect and fetch data from the Postgres database. I want to use pagination to fetch a large number of records from my database into a few records at a time. Let's say I have 1000 records of data, I need to fetch 20 data at a time with a total number of records. Below is my table and I have used the inner join to fetch data.

```
#Emplyee table

| employee-id  | employee_name | empolyee_email|       
| -----------  | --------------|-------------  |
| 1            | ABC           |abc@mail.com   |
| 2            | xyz           |xyz@mail.com   |


# Account table

| account  | employee-id    | account-balnce | created_at|
| -------- | ----------     |--------------- |-----------|
| 1        | 1              |   2000         | 22/10/2021|
| 2        | 2              |   5000         | 01/09/2021|
```

Query which I used to fetch data.

```
let employee_account = employee::table
            .inner_join(account::table.on(employee::dsl::employee_id.eq(account::dsl::employee_id)),)
            .filter(account::dsl::employee_id.eq(employeeId))
            .load::<(Employee_Details,)>(&self.pool.get()?)?;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I explored the Diesel doc and find the `limit` ([doc](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.limit)) and `offset` ([doc](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.offset)) functions look promising for implementing pagination. Please try to add these two functions before the `load` function like below. Initialize page_size with 20 and offset with 0. Loop until no data returns. Increase the offset by the page size to load next page.

```
let page_size = 20;
let mut offset = 0;

loop {
    let employee_account = employee::table
            .inner_join(account::table.on(employee::dsl::employee_id.eq(account::dsl::employee_id)),)
            .filter(account::dsl::employee_id.eq(employeeId))
            .limit(page_size)
            .offset(offset)
            .load::<(Employee_Details,)>(&self.pool.get()?)?;
    if employee_account.len() <= 0 { break;}
    offset += page_size;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay, it works when the `Id primary key`  is increment number, when `Id 
 is UUID` its does not work.

Comment: Please try and see if the issue with UUID key is gone by sorting the results with the order function prior to the limit and offset. Sorry I don't have an environment to verify.

Comment: thank you, i ll check and update !